# ASP.NET WebForms WebSite - controls changes their's values in codebehind but not on frontend

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, popup, buttonclick

I will try my best to express what I do not understand about WebForms. Maybe somone can explain it to me....

1. I work in 'quite big' WebForms (website) Application.
2. Application already has a PopUp (which I HAVE TO USE, because I dont have time to make a new one) like MessageBox in Winforms, but:

   - it's place is in MasterPage.master (I use it like ((MasterPage)Poup.Show("blablabla", yes_no));
   - I can add buttons to it and change style etc.
   - it doenst stop application (like .ShowDialog() in WinForms), so I have to assign onClick events dynamicly and assign/catch them on Page_Load to go to the wanted method depending on users input on form. At the moment i can't to anything about it.

And here is the problem:

Depending on form validation, if users press a button (on a form) - then form realods it's TextBox.Text's values and changes DropDownLists's SelectedIndexes and SelectedValues.

BUT IF YOU GO TO THE SAME METHOD WITH MY POPUP WINDOW:

**ex: Do you confirm? YES/NO**

If you press You press ANY button, then: **CHANGES ARE VISIBLE BY CODEBEHIND BUT TEXTBOXES ARE STILL VISIBLE WITH PREVIOUS DATA ON THE SCREEN, ALSO DROPDOWNLISTS HAVE OLD VALUES SELECTED**

**BUT IF YOU PRESS A FORM BUTTON (WHATEVER WHICH), EVEN IF IT'S METHOD DOES NOTHING - ALL FORM WILL "RELOAD" AND HAVE PROPER DATA ON THE SCREEN.**

(it's not about Runat="server" or AutoPostBack, I checked it)

I dont event know what to do about it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update panels are used to partial refresh of some fields inside him, caused by certain triggers, like buttons, textchanged, etc.

See more about update panel's:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx
- http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers
- http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/IntroductionUpdatePanel.aspx

Answer (score 0):

(Haven't worked with web forms events in a while, just answering in case nobody else does.)

Out of curiosity, what happens if, in your javascript handler for your popop button, you getElementById one of the form buttons on the main page and call ".click()" on it?

The basic problem sounds like there's a runat/server form on the main page, with certain behaviors associated with it, which is submitted by the main page runat server buttons but not by your popup JS.

Easy enough to test with the above approach.  If that works, take a step further and try to figure out why it worked, based on what those buttons are doing.

(If you're not using JS at all for the popup, then View Source the output HTML, because I'm sure *it* is.  Backtracking those calls should help you understand the trace from popup button press to form submission.)

Answer (score 0):

I probably mislead you by "OnClick", it's NOT javascript OnClick="method()" issue.

I mean ClickEvent on a button (in codebehind). For Ex. If form is validated I have to do:

```
ViewState["PopUpSelection"] = "yes_no";
(MasterPage)PopUp.Show("blabla",yes_no) //loads popup from MasterPage;
return;
```

then on Page_Load I have:

```
**if (string)ViewState["PopUpSelection"] == "yes_no"
{
     ButtonConfirmYes.Click += new EventHandler(MyMethod);
}**
```

And if method "MyMethod" is called from a **FORM** button, everything "**will go ok**".

If you call the same method **from PopUp** button: changes are visible by codebehind, but on the screen nothing happens, unless i press **ANY FORM BUTTON**, whatever it does